# Suggested values from the database

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

i want to suggested text values when user can type the letter in particular text box for example i will type a in my text box it will be retrieve all a value from the database and it suggested (eg: i type "a" means Air, apple, append like that) in mvc 2

Comment: With what do you need help though?

Comment: Take a look at a JavaScript autocomplete library such as http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not posted any code that you tried but if you want from scratch then have a look at following

This Jquery plugin might help you http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. On clicking View Source you can get all the code.

You can also have a look at this code http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Answer (score 1):

i think this might help. You type in a name and it brings up suggestions from a database.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

hope this is what you are looking for